# Making the distinction between position and time in a gravitational system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, units

Say we have a large spherical shell of thickness $R$ floating in space. The shell has a hole of negligible radius punched into one side that allows for a ball of mass $m$ to pass through. Say now that this ball that sits along the axis perpendicular to the plane of the hole is at some distance $r_0$ from the centre of the shell, whereby it is just on the cusp of the shell's potential well (I.e potential is 0). As time progresses from $t=0$, the ball begins to traverse towards the shell's centre of mass.

At some point the ball reaches the bottom of this potential well, but yet when it reaches the centre of the shell, its potential is 0, i.e. we have appeared to have travelled all the way down the potential well and then gone back up.

Now, I understand that the ball, despite having zero potential, is essentially trapped on a sort of island in this potential well, with any deviation from the $r=0$ point causing oscillations that eventually (if they aren't strong enough) results in the ball coming back to $r=0$ . However, if you look at this from an energy perspective, we have travelled from some point $r = r_0$ to $r=0$, with an apparent change in energy of $\Delta E = 0$, thus the work done is $0$. Though this ball is effectively confined to the centre of the  shell, we can say that this ball's position has just increased as time has progressed without any expenditure of energy, i.e. the position is just a number that, like time, increases.

So assuming that my logic so far is not flawed, how can we make the distinction (in this system) between position and time? Since if they are just increasing with respect to one another, then how are they fundamentally different? Are they, like mass and energy, the same quantity measured in different units?

Or, are the foundations of my physics jenga tower questionable at best? Thanks for reading. Looking forward to your thoughts!

Comment: The hole in the mass of the shell would have to be non negligible for there to be any net g affecting the ball inside the shell. So how does the ball begin to traverse towards the shell's com? Apologies if I am misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yet when it reaches the centre of the shell, its potential is 0,

This is incorrect. Here is a plot of the potential for your scenario for the situation where $R<<r_0$

[image: Gravitational potential for a hollow shell]

Inside the shell the field is 0, but the potential is non-zero. The absence of a field means that the potential is uniform, not that it is zero. The potential is continuous, so inside the shell the potential is $-\frac{GM}{r_0}$

After resolving this mistake, all of the rest of the question is seen to be based on a flawed premise and so it goes away.